# Escaping with HTMLENTITIES

Tags: php, opencart, html-entities, html-escape-characters

I am trying to escape some HTML in forms for an open cart site - it is custom coding with session data that is throwing me off. Currently I have:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $this->session->data['persline_2']; ?>" name="persline_2" id="persline_2" class="keyboardInput" style="width:200px" maxlength="30" />
```

I attempted to use:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities$this->session->data['persline_2']; ?>" name="persline_2" id="persline_2" class="keyboardInput" style="width:200px" maxlength="30" />
```

but this did not do the trick.  I thought `htmlentities` should begin before the variable.

This is in open cart FYI using PHP under their MVC.

Comment: You need parentheses around the item you want to use `htmlentities` on .. you should be more specific about what "did not do the trick" means as well.  Error messages / expected / actual behavior will all go a long way to helping us answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `<?php echo htmlentities($this->session->data['persline_2']); ?>` note the parentheses `()`